# how to add a foreign key using an existing column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following table called transactions and I want to add foreign key using column account_id. But when I execute the query (see below) 0 rows affected. I am not getting what is wrong with the query.

I have two tables called transactions and accounts. Accounts table has an id as primary key and an account has_many transactions.

**transactions table**

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_number      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| m_number            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| registration_number | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page_number         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| entry_date          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| narration           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| voucher_number      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| debit_credit        | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| profit              | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| account_code        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| balance             | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| branch              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| account_id          | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE transactions ADD FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**accounts table**

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_number  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| account_code    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| branch          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| father_name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nic_number      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mohalla         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| village         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nominee         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| relationship    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| opening_balance | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| opening_date    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**After running the query shouldn't the column say F_K or something like PRI ?**
Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: your query is fine. `0 rows affected` simply means no data in any of the rows was changed, which is the desired result when adding a foreign key

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE transactions; your query is perfect right but does not affect any row in database that's why return `0 rows affected`

Comment: ohh silly me! But is this correct way of adding foreign key when the column and tables are existing ?

Comment: @amjad Yes it's correct way to add foreign key...